# Adapt Connection Pool Code to Work with Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg, tortoise-orm

Can the following code, which I copied from https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/, be tailored to use Tortoise ORM?

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, create_async_engine

from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector

async def init_connection_pool(connector: Connector) -> AsyncEngine:
    # initialize Connector object for connections to Cloud SQL
    async def getconn() -> asyncpg.Connection:
            conn: asyncpg.Connection = await connector.connect_async(
                "project:region:instance",  # Cloud SQL instance connection name
                "asyncpg",
                user="my-user",
                password="my-password",
                db="my-db-name"
                # ... additional database driver args
            )
            return conn

    # The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used along with SQLAlchemy using the
    # 'async_creator' argument to 'create_async_engine'
    pool = create_async_engine(
            "postgresql+asyncpg://",
            async_creator=getconn,
    )
    return pool

async def main():
    # initialize Connector object for connections to Cloud SQL
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    async with Connector(loop=loop) as connector:
        # initialize connection pool
        pool = await init_connection_pool(connector)

        # example query
        async with pool.connect() as conn:
        await conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT NOW()"))

        # dispose of connection pool
        await pool.dispose()
```

The above code currently uses SQLAlchemy and I'd much rather use Tortoise ORM.